# Copy file paths to clipboard in OSX doesn't work with files on a server...workaround not working with multiple files

Tags: macos, applescript, finder, automator

I'm using automator to achieve this. Here's the applescript code I'm using (found elsewhere on here):

```
get the clipboard
set the clipboard to (replacement of "/Volumes/" by "afp://servername.com/" for the result)
on replacement of oldDelim by newDelim for sourceString
    set oldTIDs to text item delimiters of AppleScript
    set text item delimiters of AppleScript to oldDelim
    set strtoks to text items of sourceString
    set text item delimiters of AppleScript to newDelim
    set joinedString to strtoks as string
    set text item delimiters of AppleScript to oldTIDs
    joinedString
end replacement
get the clipboard
set the clipboard to (replacement of "/Volumes/" by "afp://servername.com/" for the result)
```

This works perfectly unless I select multiple files. Can anyone help? This code seems to fail when the input is multiple file paths.

Comment: Welcome to SO!  Can you edit your post to provide a little more detail as to what isn't working?  For instance, do you get an error?  Does nothing seem to happen at all?

Comment: No error. It only copies the first file. The answer below worked perfectly though -- thanks!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You might use workflows like this:

[image]

```
on run {input, parameters}
    set output to {}
    repeat with f in input
        set end of output to replace(POSIX path of f, "/Volumes/", "afp://servername.com/")
    end repeat
    set text item delimiters to linefeed
    set the clipboard to (output as text)
end run
on replace(input, search, replace)
    set text item delimiters to search
    set ti to text items of input
    set text item delimiters to replace
    ti as text
end replace
```

[image]

```
sed 's|/Volumes/|afp://servername.com/|'|LC_CTYPE=UTF-8 pbcopy
```

Comment: You rock! Can I add one more feature to this? I'd like to also replace any spaces in the clipboard with "%20". Is there a way to make the shell script do that?

Comment: Nevermind! I learned some sed basics and I was able to figure it out. Had to use -e and g to replace all instances.